# Geoprocessing using large image service in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, request, image-service, multi-values

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

I'm trying to use the *Extract Multi-Values to Points* tool on an image service raster layer. It runs, but just produces a column of `<Null>` in the attributes. I've done a bit of research and think this is due to the maximum request limit.

I've tried using the *Make Image Server Layer* tool, but this produced the following warning:

> WARNING 000950: Output raster exceeds the size limitation (rows: 4100
> and columns: 15000) defined on the image server. Please input smaller
> extent.

and the *Extract Multi-Values to Points* tool still returned `<Null>` values.

How can I get around this? I wonder if it would be possible to loop through the image service, using image server layers of 15000x4100 and performing Extract Multi-Values to Points on those?

Comment: Is there a mismatch between the spatial reference of the raster and the point feature class?

Comment: They are both British National Grid.